# Returning data from run method/thread to update GUI

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Map map = new SimpleMap();
    try {
        // Set System Look and Feel
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainFrame frame = new MainFrame(map);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    MainThread Main = new MainThread();
    Thread main = new Thread(Main);
    main.start();
}
```

I have this main Method which is supposed to draw a map from the data of  a Lego - Robot,
the main - Thread is supposed to process the data it gets from the robot:

```
public class MainThread implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
    final Map map = new SimpleMap();
    Point pos = new Point(0, 0);
    int[] measured = { 0x40, 0x00, 0x02, 0x13, 0x00, 0x03, 0x23, 0xFF,
            0x30, 0x2E, 0x2D, 0x2E, 0x30, 0x3F, 0x3E, 0x3C, 0x3C, 0x3C,
            0x3D, 0x3D, 0x3F, 0x5E, 0x5F, 0x5F, 0xFE, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF,
            0xFF, 0xFF, 0x6B, 0x69, 0x68, 0x68, 0x69, 0x69, 0x6C, 0xFF,
            0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    map.put(new Square(pos, false));
    //
    // System.out.println("measure");
    // int[] measured;
    // try {
    // measured = robot.measure();
    // } catch (CommandErrorException e) {
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // return;
    // }
    map.processMeasureData(measured, pos, Orientation.NORTH);
}
```

}

How can i get the data from the thread to update the GUI?

Comment: You can pass the frame to thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can not return a value from run method of thread.
All you can do is call another method in run and pass that value as parameter in that method and do what ever processing you want to do.
I hope it will help you.
Feel free to ask again if not solved.